# SQL error converting data type varchar to bigInt

Tags: sql

I have this query in which `Message.controlId is` big int and the concatenated `Data` variable has a unique identifier but I am getting the above mentioned error.

Here is my query:

```
 M = conn:execute({live=true,sql="Select * from Events join dbo.Messages on Events.EventId = Messages.TriggerEventId where Messages.ControlId= '"..Data.."'"})
```

Comment: Have you tried casting to varchar?  CAST(Messages.ControlId AS Varchar(max)) = ...

Comment: @TMNT2014: I have only uniqueidentifier in Messages.ControlId field and event the simplest select statement "select * from Messages.ControlIf- "some mesage GUID' is giving that error, while the same statement is working in SQL AZURE, any particular reason for that?

Comment: Your `Data` variable is not an integer, that's what the message is already telling you.

Comment: @Simrankaur uniqueidentifier as in a GUID ?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: Yes, Right.  The value is '6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF' which I am not able to compare with the value in Messages.ControlId field

Comment: @Simrankaur then I am not sure how its working on SQL AZURE, double check if "Messages.ControlId" is a bigint column in Azure